# Custom formatting for a time using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I'm having difficulty with formatting a time using `moment.js`. I decided to try out `angular-moment` and was faced with some limitations, and after looking at the documentation for `moment.js`, it seems that it would be a lot better to create a custom directive which uses `moment`. Here lies my problem, I have some experience and knowledge of basic directives, but I'm not sure how to move forward with creating a directive which uses `moment` to format a date/time. So, here are the rules I want to adhere to:

Less than 1 minute ago: print as `a few seconds ago`
More than 1 minute ago && less than 1 hour ago: print as `X minutes ago`
More than 1 hour ago: print as `h:mm a`
Yesterday (This should compare the two days to see if it is today or yesterday): print as `Yesterday`
More than yesterday: print as `MMM DD`

So I'm unsure where to start really, and any help is welcome!

Comment: Did you try out, timefrom? http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/

Comment: @SwarajGiri I'll take a look, my biggest issue is with transferring that into a working directive

Comment: @SwarajGiri A very inefficient way of handling `from` could be to say if `a.from(b) === 'a day ago'` then `return 'Yesterday'` but that seems a dumb way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moment.js is the way to go! I recommend you use [angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) instead of directive.

Here is how you might implement one with moment.js [fromNow function](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/):

```
var fromNow = function () {
        return function (value, format) {
            return moment(value).fromNow();
        };
    };

    angular.module('myApp').filter('fromNow', fromNow);
```

And you simply call it from html:

```
<span>{{player.activeSince | fromNow}}</span>
```

Comment: First, thanks for suggesting to use a filter with fromNow as that's shortened down my code a lot as I was trying to use a directive before which seems unnecessary when you can achieve it with this. How would you go about editing this `fromNow` function to add in some conditions as I mentioned above? Using this right now with use Moment's `defaultRelativeTime` settings such as `a month ago` etc. I'd like to have some special cases as above, where in some cases I will need to take the hour or minute from the time. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: have you tried to configure relativeTime? http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/ if you have some business logic which adds or reduces time, it should be doing it in controller.

Comment: I have tried editing the `relativeTime` settings, and I understand how to do this to change it from one string to another, but I don't understand how I would add some business logic to the `relativeTime` settings according to my original post.

Comment: as i understand you want a different format depending on value. i think fromNow function cant do this alone, so in filter you have to check if value is greater than 24h and return moment().format()

Comment: How would you check if value is greater than 24h? I've been trying to extract this information for ages with no luck

Comment: you subtract 24 hours from now and check if it is after given value. take a look at http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/ and http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/

Comment: So for example, within the filter, you would create some variables such as `oneHourAgo` by doing now.subtract(1, 'hour'). You would then check this doing something like `if (date.isBefore(oneHourAgo) return date.format(something)` Hope I understood correctly, I'll have a go now

Comment: I've been trying to get this working with no luck. I have tried even checking something as simple as `oneHourAgo.isBefore(now)` and it isn't returning the correct results. I have logged `moment()` to console and it sends me `Mon Aug 24 2015 16:31:51 GMT+0800` which is not correct...yet the results from your original `fromNow` filter give me the correct `5 minutes ago` or `an hour ago` etc.